# Gallium makes aluminum soft like a wet tissue. Any other metals or alloys that are vulnerable to similar damage?

Tags: metal, metallurgy

Gallium can make aluminum [soft and brittle](https://youtu.be/FaMWxLCGY0U?t=73) as long as it bypasses the aluminum oxide normally formed on the surface of the aluminum (for example by scratching the surface).

Mercury can [weaken aluminum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7Ilxsu-JlY) as well.

Are there any other metals or alloys that can be "weakened" **by coming in contact** with gallium, mercury or any other substance?

Comment: Any? Better ask about ones then don't...

Comment: Amalgam#Liste_amalgam-bildender_Elemente Basically only Cr, Mo, W, and Mn, Fe, Co are safe.

Comment: Just found the term. It's called embrittlement.  It can occur even on steel (hydrogen embrittlement). Hopefully someone will post a comprehensive answer, otherwise i'll post one.

Comment: I want to add that you probably refer to simple contact. Otherwise there should be plenty of alloys and metallic solids that suffer of embrittlement. Some are well known and still useful.

Comment: @Alchimista You are right, I'll edit the question to highlight it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gallium and Mercury, the latter in particular are absolute pests and poisons to most metals. There are too many to mention that will suffer the same consequences. I will mention the few that don't. Iron, Platinum, Tungsten and Tantalum all tolerate them fairly well. There are certainly more examples, but the common rule is; most don't.